# Select individual keyframe in an fcurve using blender python

Tags: python, animation, scripting

I have this code that selects a particular fcurve (Z Location in this case) and moves keyframes 2 frames forward.

But it selects the entire fcurve with all keyframes in that fcurve.

How can I select a single keyframe in a fcurve?

Suppose I want to only move keyframe on frame 48 to frame 62. How can I do that?

```
import bpy

# Configuration
action_name = 'CubeAction'
data_path = 'location'
index = 2                   # Z axis

# Find the appropriate action
action = bpy.data.actions.get(action_name)
if action:
    # From this action, retrieve the appropriate F-Curve
    fcurve = action.fcurves.find(data_path = data_path, index = index)
    if fcurve:
        # Iterate over all keyframes
        for kfp in fcurve.keyframe_points:
            # Print current keyframe info
            print('Frame = {:04}; Value = {}'.format(kfp.co[0], kfp.co[1]))
            # Change keyframe data
            # Push back in time by 2 frames
            kfp.co[0] += 2
```

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`keyframe_points`](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.FCurve.html#bpy.types.FCurve.keyframe_points) has `[]` semantics, so you simply look them up:

```py
for index in range(48, 63):
    fcurve.keyframe_points[index] += 2
```

Note that [`range`](https://cs.stanford.edu/people/nick/py/python-range.html) has "less than" semantics so if you want to include frame 62, you have to use 63.

Comment: Thanks Marty. It works.

Comment: @jugaadanimation you're welcome.